# NSTask with command-line input redirection

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix, nstask

I'm trying to learn writing a **NSTask** in such a way that the *task* process can accept *input file redirection* as argument. In traditional unix *system()* command this is trivial to code, but too far from being controllable enough for the demands of my app. The example of what I'm trying to understand is *which* argument belongs *where*. This is the full command, as would be typed into *stdin* or passed to *system()*:

```
cd /Users/Shared ; /usr/local/bin/C_command < /Users/Shared/s.txt
```

where ***C_command*** stands for a standard *unix* command-line tool which accepts input arguments redirected to be read from a file, exactly as written. Launch path would then be:

```
task.launchPath = @"/usr/local/bin/C_command";
```

Current directory would have to be:

```
task.currentDirectoryPath = @"/Users/Shared";
```

If putting the following as argument:

```
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat: @" < /Users/shared/s.txt"], nil];
```

or even this:

```
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat: @" < "], [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/Users/shared/s.txt"], nil];
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong and missing something evidently important, but can't figure out what. A hint is very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input redirection just uses the contents of a file instead of the contents of stdin. You have to hook up the `NSTask` object's stdin to the file. Something like this should work:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSFileHandle *stdin = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/Users/shared/s.txt"];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/local/bin/C_command"];
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/Shared"];
[task setStandardInput:stdin];
```

Comment: This is really brilliant. I could find absolutely no documentation on the web on this, or it probably exists buried somewhere too deep in the API Reference files. What surprises me most of all is that it needs no `NSArray *args`, which is logical, in fact. I consider the question answered.